# Does a portfolio on efficient frontier also lie on CML(capital market line)?

Tags: risk, modern-portfolio-theory, capm, standard-deviation

I am trying to solve this question:

Assume that CAPM is true. The risk-free rate is 3%, the expected return on the market portfolio is 10% and the standard deviation of the return on the market portfolio is 15%. Consider a portfolio P with expected return of 25% and assume that it is on the efficient frontier.

Question: What is the standard deviation of the portfolio?

After I read the question, I immediately think of using CML to calculate the portfolio standard deviation: $$R_p = r_f + \frac{E[R_m] - r_f}{\sigma_m}\sigma_p$$

However, the question states that the portfolio lies on the efficient frontier. My concern is, the efficient frontier has a concave look; on the other hand, the CML is a line connects the point $(0, r_f)$ and tangent to the market portfolio which also lies on the efficient frontier. So wouldn't any portfolio on the efficient frontier necessarily lie below the CML? How should one calculate the standard deviation in this case?[image]

For example, the red point represents the portfolio of interest; clearly, it is below the CML. What approach should I adopt to calculate its standard deviation?

Comment: Technically, as soon as a risk-free asset enters the Markowitz world, the efficient frontier becomes a straight line, tangential to the "old" efficient frontier which was based purely on risky investments.

Comment: @Kermittfrog This solves my issue; I can see that the CML becomes the new efficient frontier because portfolios on the CML are feasible, and they dominate those on the "old" frontier. Thank you.